# Can I store a method in a variable in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is it possible to store a method into a variable? Something like

```
 public void store() {
     SomeClass foo = <getName() method>;
     //...
     String value = foo.call();
 }

 private String getName() {
     return "hello";
 }
```

I think this is possible with lambdas but I don't know how.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, you can have a variable reference to any method. For simple methods it's usually enough to use [`java.util.function.*` classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). Here's a working example:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Consumer<Integer> simpleReference = Main::someMethod;
        simpleReference.accept(1);

        final Consumer<Integer> another = i -> System.out.println(i);
        another.accept(2);
    }

    private static void someMethod(int value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

If your method does not match any of those interfaces, you can define your own. The only requirement is that is must have a single abstract method.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        final MyInterface foo = Main::test;
        final String result = foo.someMethod(1, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static String test(int foo, int bar, int baz) {
        return "hello";
    }

    @FunctionalInterface // Not required, but expresses intent that this is designed 
                         // as a lambda target
    public interface MyInterface {
        String someMethod(int foo, int bar, int baz);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get some error how you can only do this in a static context. :/

Comment: If the method you're trying to reference is not static, then you can reference it using "this::test" where the "test" is the function name.

Answer (score 14):

You can use Java 8 method references. You can use the `::` 'operator' to grab a method reference from an object.

```
import java.util.function.IntConsumer;

class Test {
    private int i;
    public Test() { this.i = 0; }
    public void inc(int x) { this.i += x; }
    public int get() { return this.i; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        IntConsumer c = t::inc;
        c.accept(3);
        System.out.println(t.get());
        // prints 3
    }
}
```

You just need a `@FunctionalInterface` that matches the signature of the method you want to store. `java.util.function` contains a selection of the most commonly used ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use method reference like -

```
System.out::println
```

Which is equivalent to the lambda expression -

```
x -> System.out.println(x).
```

Moreover you can user reflection to store method and it will works for the earlier version of `java` too.